# Smarter word break in CSS?

Tags: css, word-break

If I just put `word-break: break-all` on an element, I often end up with this:

> Hello people, I am typing a mes
>   sage that's too long to fit!

Obviously this would be much better as:

> Hello people, I am typing a
>   message that's too long to fit!

But at the same time if someone writes:

> BLAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHH!!!!!!

Then I'd want it to be:

> BLAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRR
>   RGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHH!!!!!!

I can't seem to find a way to actually do this.

Note that the width of the element is not fixed and may change.

Comment: Try `word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word`? (I don't use CSS above a very primitive level, or know how it's handled, but it "seems like it might work".

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try [`word-break: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) it should behave as you expect.

Comment: `word-break: break-word` is non-standard for webkit, having the same problem as op [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190420/firefox-word-break-breaks-short-words-at-random-points/14191114#14191114) answer solves it.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` didn't work for me; it had no effect.  I have text in a table cell and the table is contained in a div with `max-width: 1000px`  Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The edit at Dec 2015 is probably not appropriate, it changed the answer totally. The old answer `word-break: break-word;` is not standard, but it actually works in my chrome. The new answer (after editing) `word-wrap: break-word;` does not work at all. IMHO directly editing the answer in this way seems to be confusing to the readers.

Comment: For me `word-wrap: break-word;` works when I specify a width, no matter the unit. So, by specifying `width: 100%` I was able to make it work. However, I won't be upvoting this answer because the edit completely changes the answer (it wasn't a typo, it was downright another css property) and it wasn't even written by the original poster.

Answer (score 46):

For a lot of our projects we usually add this where necessary:

```
.text-that-needs-wrapping {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

It handles most odd situations with different browsers.

Comment: Quick demo showing hyphen, word and break all happening.
http://plnkr.co/plunk/uKaAc0FddZfs7pxl

Comment: @RichardCollette I don't think your example shows the hyphen though.

Answer (score 7):

The updated answer should be:

`overflow-wrap:break-word;`

It will break a word that by itself would not be able to fit on its own line, but leave all other words as they are (see overflow-wrap [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)).

You could also use:

`overflow-wrap:anywhere;` but this will allow line breaks after any word in an effort to reduce the width of an element. See the difference described below from MDN:

> [break-word is] The same as the anywhere value, with normally unbreakable words allowed to be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line, but soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break are NOT considered when calculating min-content intrinsic sizes.

Also, `anywhere` is not supported by Internet Explore, Safari, and some mobile browsers while `break-word` is supported on all major browsers (see [here][2]).

`word-break: break-word;` should no longer be used because it is deprecated in favor of the `overflow-wrap:break-word;`. Now, the `word-break` property is intended to be used when you want to break words regardless of whether they could fit on their own line (i.e. the OP's first example with `word-break: break-all`.

> In contrast to word-break, overflow-wrap will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

(From overflow-wrap [also linked above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) )

Answer (score 4):

For smart word breaks, or for *correct* word breaks in the first place, you need language-dependent rules. For English and many other languages, the correct breaking means hyphenation, with a hyphen added at the end of a line when a break occurs.

In CSS, you can use [`hyphens: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/hyphens), though you mostly still need to duplicate it using vendor prefixes. As this does not work on IE 9, you may consider JavaScript-based hyphenation like [Hyphenate.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) instead. In both cases, it is essential to use language markup (`lang` attribute).

Breaking long, unhyphenateable strings is a different issue. They would best be handled in preprocessing, but in a simple setting, `word-break: break-word` (which means *incorrect* breaking of words, in English for example) may be considered as an emergency.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support it as Firefox https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens.. just partially

Answer (score 4):

`overflow-wrap: anywhere;` is what you need.

Comment: A couple of years ago, [@Nikhil Bhatia suggested this in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835882/3025856), but also highlighted some limitations of this approach. Are their concerns no longer valid? It'd be useful to [edit] your answer to acknowledge those critiques and why you believe this remains the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This is what  youre looking for:

```
.break-word {
-ms-word-break: break-all;
-ms-word-wrap: break-all;
-webkit-word-break: break-word;
-webkit-word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
}
```