# Firefox breaks words at random points

Tags: css, firefox

I already know the existence of this question BUT, doesn't work for me

[Firefox word-break breaks short words at random points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190420/firefox-word-break-breaks-short-words-at-random-points)

As you can see from the screenshot I applied the mentioned CSS property but seems that the last version of FF broke words at will.

[image]
How can I prevent the break of "(09/03/2017)"? and put it on a new line like all the others browsers?

I also tried different settings of those property but nothing.

`word-break: keep-all;` doesn't work neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since is a date you could wrap that information in a

`<time datetime="...">`

element and apply a `white-space: nowrap` to it